# chaining reduce() and map() Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to combine reduce() with map() to reduce multiple box art objects to a single value: the url of the largest box art.
**It gives me the following error :**

```
VM272:20 Uncaught TypeError: boxarts.reduce(...).map is not a function at <anonymous>:20:4
```

Not sure what exactly is wrong

```js
const boxarts = [
  { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
  { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg" },
  { width: 300, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" },
  { width: 425, height: 150, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg" }
]
let newReduce = boxarts.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
  if (accumulator.width * accumulator.height > currentValue.width * currentValue.height) {
    return accumulator
  } else {
    return currentValue
  }
}).map(function(item) {
  return item.url
})

console.log(newReduce)
```

**SOLUTION to the initial question**. It returns the link as an array of object.

```
    const boxarts = [{
    width: 600,
    height: 700,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture600.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture500.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 425,
    height: 150,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg"
  }
]

let newReduce = [boxarts.reduce(function(acc, currentValue) {

  if (acc.width * acc.height > currentValue.width * currentValue.height) {
    return acc
  } else {
    return currentValue
  }
})].map(function(item) {
  return {
      url:item.url}
})



console.log(newReduce)
```

Comment: You are getting that error because the output of your reduce is an object.

Comment: Why do you want to chain `reduce` and `map`? What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I am trying to combine reduce() with map() to reduce multiple box art objects to a single value: the url of the largest box art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` works on an array but in your code the `reduce` method is returning an `object`, so `map` will not work. Since it is already returning an `object` you can get the url just by doing `object.url`

```js
const boxarts = [{
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 150,
    height: 200,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 425,
    height: 150,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg"
  }
]

let newReduce = boxarts.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {

  if (accumulator.width * accumulator.height > currentValue.width * currentValue.height) {
    return accumulator
  } else {
    return currentValue
  }
}).url


console.log(newReduce)
```

If you still want to use the map function put the return of reduce in an array. Then you can use map method on this. Further the map method will again return an array

```js
const boxarts = [{
    width: 150,
    height: 200,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 425,
    height: 150,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg"
  },
  {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg"
  }
]

let newReduce = [boxarts.reduce(function(acc, currentValue) {

  if (acc.width * acc.height > currentValue.width * currentValue.height) {
    return acc
  } else {
    return currentValue
  }
}, boxarts[0])].map(function(item) {
  return item.url
})
console.log(newReduce)
```

Comment: I see , but is there a way to implement chaining reduce() and map(). This is for studying purpose.

Comment: @brk Wouldn’t it make more sense to return an array of all largest box arts rather than an array of a single largest box art?

Comment: @JohnJohn What exactly do you want to map over?

Comment: @Xufox i think it is just the choice , what you are saying is also right and makes sense

Comment: now it is much better , Yes I want to return and array of largest box url

Comment: @brk Now it is working as I wanted. Sorry for confusion. I will add the solution. See updated question.

Comment: @XufoxI just want to clarify. Do I understand it correctly that the reduce does not return the array? Because initially it was an array.

Comment: @JohnJohn Which array do you mean? None of the `reduce` calls in either snippet, including your original snippet, return any array. They all return a single object.

Comment: @Xufox I was thinking since the initialValue was an array of objects it reduce() will return the object in the array.

Comment: @JohnJohn The initial value isn’t an array. `boxarts[0]` is the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const boxarts = [
        { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
        { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg" },
        { width: 300, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" },
        { width: 425, height: 150, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg" }
    ]

    let newReduce = boxarts.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {

        if (accumulator.width * accumulator.height > currentValue.width * currentValue.height) {
            return accumulator
        } else {
            return currentValue
        }
    })

    console.log(newReduce.url)
```

From your mapping function it seems that you're trying to get the `url`, the problem is `newReduce` is an object and there is no `map` function. You can easily get the url simply using `newReduce.url`

Comment: Is there a way to combine reduce() with map() to reduce multiple box art objects to a single value: the url of the largest box art?

Answer (score 1):

The result of your `reduce` call is a boxart *object*, not an array. Don't use `map`, just access the `url` property:

```js
const boxarts = [
  { width: 200, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture200.jpg" },
  { width: 150, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture150.jpg" },
  { width: 300, height: 200, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture300.jpg" },
  { width: 425, height: 150, url: "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture425.jpg" }
]
let newReduce = boxarts.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
  if (accumulator.width * accumulator.height > currentValue.width * currentValue.height) {
    return accumulator
  } else {
    return currentValue
  }
}).url

console.log(newReduce)
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine reduce() with map() to reduce multiple box art objects to a single value: the url of the largest box art?

Comment: @JohnJohn You can only do that if `reduce` returns multiple box art objects, which should be in an array.

Comment: @Barmar I just posted the update with the solution. Thx.